# Unity script when my character hits the trashbin the item i picked up must be deleted

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i am making a level of unity: In this level you have to sort the garbage.
The player can move with the arrow keys, and can pick up trash with the E key. Then take it to the right trash can. I made a script that should make the character pickup the item and then he can go to the right trashbin and if he hits the trashbin the item will be destroyed, but it does not work and I have no idea what is wrong.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class PickupItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float pickupRange = 2f;
    public LayerMask pickupLayer;
    public AudioClip pickupSound;
    public string[] pickupTags;
    public AudioClip wrongBinSound;
    public string[] trashBinTags;
    public TextMeshProUGUI itemNameText;

    private AudioSource audioSource;
    private GameObject currentObject;
    private bool holdingItem = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, pickupRange, pickupLayer))
        {
            foreach (string tag in pickupTags)
            {
                if (hit.collider.tag == tag && !holdingItem)
                {
                    currentObject = hit.collider.gameObject;
                    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
                    {
                        StartCoroutine(Pickup());
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            currentObject = null;
        }
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        foreach (string trashBinTag in trashBinTags)
        {
            if (collision.gameObject.tag == trashBinTag)
            {
                switch (currentObject.tag)
                {
                    case "paper":
                        if (trashBinTag == "TrashbinPa")
                        {
                            Debug.Log("paper in vuilbak");
                            audioSource.PlayOneShot(pickupSound);
                            
                            itemNameText.text = "";
                            holdingItem = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "glass":
                        if (trashBinTag == "TrashbinG")
                        {
                            Debug.Log("glass in vuilbak");
                            audioSource.PlayOneShot(pickupSound);
                            Destroy(currentObject);
                            itemNameText.text = "";
                            holdingItem = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "metal":
                        if (trashBinTag == "TrashbinM")
                        {
                            Debug.Log("metal in vuilbak");
                            audioSource.PlayOneShot(pickupSound);
                            Destroy(currentObject);
                            itemNameText.text = "";
                            holdingItem = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "plastic":
                        if (trashBinTag == "TrashbinP")
                        {
                            Debug.Log("plastic in vuilbak");
                            audioSource.PlayOneShot(pickupSound);
                            Destroy(currentObject);
                            itemNameText.text = "";
                            holdingItem = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        audioSource.PlayOneShot(wrongBinSound);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Pickup()
    {
        if (currentObject != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Object picked up");
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(pickupSound);
            currentObject.SetActive(false);
            itemNameText.text = "Inventory: " + currentObject.name;
            holdingItem = true;
        }
    }

}
```

My character settings:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oTRy.png)

One of mine Trashbin(Glass):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyU0Z.png)

One of mine Trash items(Wine bottle):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmJtY.png)

I don't know what i'm doing wrong can someone help me?

I tried to debug but no outcome. I can pickup the item but i cannot hit the trashbin so it can delete the item. I use tags for the right trashbin which also use tags.

Comment: Please adjust the tags properly: this is C#, not unityscript. UnityScript is obsolete. Please give us more details about the debugging. How deep into the branches can you step, which part gets executed and which gets skipped? Also, that `Update()` is really unoptimized. Since `currentObject` is irrelevant until picked up and since it should only be picked up when pressing E, try moving `if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))` at the beginning of `Update()` else you'll have Raycasts executing each frame, not to mention the `foreach` that follows. Both add a LOT of overhead each frame for nothing.

Comment: All the tags has been checked and they are right, i tried making a debug.log in multiple if/switch statements but the only thing that works is that it picks up the item and it becomes disabled and after when i go with the character to the right trashbin and i hit it with my character it does'nt do anything, nor the debug log will pop up

Comment: Try a debugging session, please. Using `Debug.Log()` is not actual debugging. Once you debug the code you can see all "connected" references and the context (use  the **Autos** and **Locals** debugging windows). Then you can tell us what steps in and out of the blocks occurred. Debugging is a vital technique that must be learned as soon as one gets familiar with a programming language. For example, where does code execution stop in `OnCollisionEnter()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so let's take it one step at a the time. First of all, that code needs a lot of optimization as it's a FPS-drop nightmare.

```
private void Update()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, pickupRange, pickupLayer))
    {
        foreach (string tag in pickupTags)
        {
            if (hit.collider.tag == tag && !holdingItem)
            {
                currentObject = hit.collider.gameObject;
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
                {
                    StartCoroutine(Pickup());
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        currentObject = null;
    }
}
```

Here you are raycasting every frame regardless of the player wanting to pick up the trash or not (i.e. hitting the <kbd>E</kbd> key). This doesn't make much sense. As I said in my comment, this check `if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))` should be a lot earlier.

Also, if the player has `holdingItem == true`, raycasting to search for additional trash doesn't really make sense if the player can only carry one trash at a time. So you can optimize that code out this way. I would even argue that holdingItem will cause conflicts since the same effect can be achieved by using `currentObject != null`, therefore, I'll recycle `holdingItem`.

Next, iterating through lists each frame, also adds overhead. If you see the `break`, you actually call it only if this condition `if (hit.collider.tag == tag && !holdingItem)` is fulfilled. That means that regardless of holding an item or pressing <kbd>E</kbd>, as long as the player stares at some trash, you will Raycast each frame, iterate through the list each frame and compare the tag.

I mentioned tag compare. Comparing tags as string also adds some overhead. Please see `GameObject.CompareTag()` as that is the proper way to efficiently compare tags. Also learn how conditions work, both for *or* as well as for *and*. In your case you chose the most inefficient way to compare:

`if (hit.collider.tag == tag && !holdingItem)`

Even if you would choose *NOT* to use `CompareTag()` (although you should use it), this will always be more efficient:

`if (!holdingItem && hit.collider.tag == tag)`

This is because if the player holds an item, the next condition is skipped. When using *or* and *and* clauses in conditions always use the least expensive and most common one first.

The `else` is also dodgy there. That means that if the player holds an object, that object will be set to `null` if a Raycast doesn't hit anything in range. This might be the reason why your trash destruction fails.

This should be better, I think:

```
private void Update()
{
    if (currentObject == null && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, pickupRange, pickupLayer))
        {
            holdingItem = false; // you have a 1 second delay in Pickup()

            // no delay here
            foreach (string tag in pickupTags)
            {
                if (!holdingItem && hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag(tag))
                {
                    holdingItem = true; // stops overlaps
                    StartCoroutine(Pickup(hit.collider.gameObject));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

IEnumerator Pickup(GameObject trash)
{
    if (holdingItem && trash != null && currentObject == null)
    {
        #if UNITY_EDITOR
            // don't include this outside tests
            Debug.Log(trash.tag + " picked up");
        #endif

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        audioSource.PlayOneShot(pickupSound);
        currentObject = trash;
        currentObject.SetActive(false);
        itemNameText.text = "Inventory: " + currentObject.name;
    }
}
```

Next, let's look at the trash bin.

There is a ton of repeated code that can just be simplified away. Easier for maintenance too, not to mention bug fixes.

This is how I'd write `OnCollisionEnter()`:

```
private void ThrowTrashAway()
{
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
        // don't include this outside tests
        Debug.Log(currentObject.tag + " in vuilbak");
    #endif
    audioSource.PlayOneShot(pickupSound);
    Destroy(currentObject);
    currentObject = null;
    itemNameText.text = "";
    holdingItem = false;

}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (currentObject == null)
        return; // don't execute anything

    if ((collision.gameObject.CompareTag("TrashbinPa") && currentObject.CompareTag("paper"))
    || (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("TrashbinG") && currentObject.CompareTag("glass"))
    || (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("TrashbinM") && currentObject.CompareTag("metal"))
    || (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("TrashbinP") && currentObject.CompareTag("plastic")))
         ThrowTrashAway();
    else
         audioSource.PlayOneShot(wrongBinSound);
}
```

Also keep in mind you don't destroy paper trash in your original code, like you do with other types of trash. So if you tested with paper, it wouldn't have worked anyway.

At first glance I'd say it's because of how you originally wrote the code in `Update()`. Of course this is also blind guessing since you haven't provided any debugging info regarding what steps the code executed in each branch on the stack nor did you tell us how each log call was or wasn't called. Regardless of whether you apply the suggestions, at least keep the concept in mind for further projects. Just because checking something in `Update()` is easier doesn't mean you have to do it there.

Still, as I said in my comment, the best way to really know why your code did not execute is a debugging session (not `Debug.Log()` calls, although they can help as well but they should **never** replace real debugging).

Let us know how it turned out.

Comment: Thank you this really made my code better and i understand more what i did wrong!

Comment: Glad to have helped :) Keep in mind there are a lot of more things you can do to improve. For example naming the bin tags like the trash: `Plastic` + `TrashbinPlastic` instead of `TrashninP`. Same for *glass* and the others. This lets you simplify code like `string trash; string bin = Trashbin` and have `bin = bin+trash` to concatenate *Trashbin* with *Plastic* and result **TrashbinPlastic**. Of course that means redoing all the layers and it might not be worth it if the project is advanced enough, but keep in mind for other projects. Then you can have more dynamic, cleaner and simpler code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your switch statement is doing, since `currentObject` gets disabled when it gets picked up (`currentObject.SetActive(false);`). By disabling it, the raycast in your `Update()` method will not find anything, and `currentObject` will be set to `null` every frame.

This will prevent any of your destruction code from running inside the `OnCollisionEnter()` method.

I would suggest either not disabling the `currentObject`, or pausing the raycast in `Update()` when an object is being held. This will allow the switch statement to run inside the collision method, and should destroy your object.

Comment: That's partly incorrect. Why would it be set to null? It doesn't get destroyed. It's true that engine calls are no longer executed, but the object is not set as null once it is inactive.

Comment: I tried deleting the currentObject.SetActive(false); but it doesnt change anything nor did pausing the raycast in Update() works. I tried debugging it but still didn't got an answer

Comment: @TheNomad Wouldn't it be set to null since after being deactivated, the raycast finds nothing in update of the next frame and the else statement sets it to null?

Comment: In `Update()` he picks up the trash. That code is dubious to me too with that else (which is why I said to take out the `Input` check at a higher branch. That means it would be null regardless of it being active or not. Still, I was looking there too but for other reasons. But I think you're close too. Still, it has nothing to do with the trash being active or not since a raycast would hit nothing most of the time.